# Index.diff Packages file in a Repository

Tags: linux, indexing, repository, package, cydia

I've tried googling and couldnt find much on this topic. I have this problem with my repo, I have tons of debian files that each time i scan-packages, it would take a whole lot of time to build the Packages file. I recently stumbled on to this:

[image]

It allows you to add newer packages to the repo with newer Packages file together.
Does anyone have an idea how this works? Thanks!